# Struggling to specify exact build conditions in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, devops

I'm struggling to make Azure devops run builds in exactly the way I need it to. Right now, I have a solution where the second stage is always skipped unless the build was triggered by a schedule. This is mostly fine but is a nightmare in the rare times that we would need to run the second stage manually. Here is how I have achieved that:

`- stage: second_stage`
`condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')`
(I can't work out how to linebreak code here!)

**What I want to achieve**

1. Both stages should run when part of a scheduled build
2. Only the first stage should be run when creating a PR or merging
3. Only the first stage should be "checked" in the UI when a manual build is run
   *but the user should have the option to check the second stage as well*

Please help! Thank you! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following yaml can meet your request.

```
stages:
- stage: first_stage
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello first_stage!
      
- stage: second_stage
  condition: or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'))
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello second_stage!
```

> Only the first stage should be "checked" in the UI when a manual build
> is run but the user should have the option to check the second stage
> as well

Please manual choose which stage you want to run here when a manual build is required.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is spot on, thank you